# UIPopoverPresentationController misplaced

Tags: ios, objective-c, ipad

I have table of items (`UITableViewController`) where I am presenting the items using customizable cells. On the left of each cell I have a thumbnail image and when you click on it (on a button above the image, to be precise), a popover appears that should show the image zoomed in. It is working well only for the first cell:

[image: Image popover looks good for the first row]

Clicking on the cells that are below shows wrongly shifted popover and the misplacement increases when you go from top to bottom of the table:

[image: Image popover looks misplaced for other rows]

I am setting up the block of each cell inside `UITableViewController`:

```
 - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView
     cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    // Get a new or recycled cell
BNRItemCell *cell =
    [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"BNRItemCell"
                                forIndexPath:indexPath];

// Set the text on the cell with the description of the item
// that is the nth index of items, where n = row this cell
// will appear in on the tableview
NSArray *items = [[BNRItemStore sharedStore] allItems];
BNRItem *item = items[indexPath.row];

// Configure the cell with the BNRItem
cell.nameLabel.text = item.itemName;
cell.serialNumberLabel.text = item.serialNumber;
cell.valueLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"$%d", item.valueInDollars];

cell.thumbnailView.image = item.thumbnail;

cell.actionBlock = ^{
    NSLog(@"Going to show image for %@", item);

    if ([UIDevice currentDevice].userInterfaceIdiom == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad){
        NSString *itemKey = item.itemKey;

        // if there is no image, we don't need to display anything
        UIImage *img = [[BNRImageStore sharedStore] imageForKey:itemKey];
        if (!img) {
            return;
        }

        BNRImageViewController *ivc = [[BNRImageViewController alloc] init];
        ivc.image = img;

        ivc.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationPopover;
        ivc.preferredContentSize = CGSizeMake(380, 300);
        CGRect frame = [self.view convertRect:cell.thumbnailView.bounds
                                     fromView:cell.thumbnailView];
        // frame.origin.y -= 150;

        UIPopoverPresentationController *popoverController = ivc.popoverPresentationController;
        popoverController.permittedArrowDirections = UIPopoverArrowDirectionUp;
        popoverController.sourceView = cell.thumbnailView;
        popoverController.sourceRect = frame;

        [self.navigationController presentViewController:ivc animated:YES completion:nil];


    }
};

return cell;
```

}

The block is executed upon clicking the button on the view of customizable `UITableViewCell`:

```
@implementation BNRItemCell

- (IBAction)showImage:(id)sender
{
if (self.actionBlock) {
    self.actionBlock();
}
}

@end
```

`actionBlock` is the `property` of `BNRItemCell`

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You're using a `cell` variable but I can't see the method that you're in to get that. Could you share which method you're in?

Comment: Actually, looking at that - have you tried replacing `cell.thumbnailView.bounds` with `cell.thumbnailView.frame`?

Comment: It is a block that I am setting in `UITableViewController` (that is responsible for drawing the table) s' method `tableView: cellForRowAtIndexPath:`. The block is then set up as a `@property` of another `UITableViewCell` (that is the customizable cell) that executes the block upon clicking the button.

Comment: Not sure I follow. Could you add more code?

Comment: Just tried it, nothing changed.

Comment: Try something like: `CGRect frame = [cell.view convertRect:cell.thumbnailView.frame toView:self.view];`

Comment: Yes, thank you! That works. How can I accept the answer?

Comment: I've added an answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try something like:

`CGRect frame = [cell.view convertRect:cell.thumbnailView.frame toView:self.view];`

The trick here is the difference between `bounds` and `frame`. In the case of a button, its frame is where it is when you look at its superview (e.g. 42,42). But, the bounds is where the button is relative to itself and its own coordinates (0,0).

Don't laugh at my drawing (I'm not a designer) but this might help:

[image]

You are asking the button (or in your case a UIImage) "where are you relative to the superview" (which in this case is basically the entire screen). You do this with `convertRect: toView:`. You convert the the *frame* of the thumbnail (not its bounds) to where its coordinates appear to be on the superview.

Comment: Could you briefly comment on what was my mistake and why your proposal actually fixes the issue?